# Error Proguard when signing Android Aplication

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, proguard

I was try to signing my Android Application with Proguard but have error like this

```
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console  
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android] Warning: com.badlogic.gdx.sqlite.android.AndroidCursor: can't find referenced method 'void log(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Exception)' in class com.badlogic.gdx.Application
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-01-28 12:04:22 - PriestsNDevils-android]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

what must i do ?.

project.properties

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
target=android-19
```

i have add proguard-android.txt

```
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.sqlite.android.AndroidCursor.**
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb -keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-dontwarn javax.jdo.** -dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.**
```

Comment: *what must i do ?.* you must(have to) learn reading the exception and follow it or at least how to use google .

Comment: Refer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246842/using-proguard-with-android

Comment: I use libgdx , there are different with native android java. so what refer for libgdx proguard with sqlite ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `proguard-android.txt` 
`-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.sqlite.android.AndroidCursor.**`

Comment: Add a -dontwarn and if you want more clarification read this forum http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=15712

Answer (score 0):

try to add this lines at the end of your proguard .cfg file

-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

-dontwarn javax.jdo.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.**